# How to control flow of async functions?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, async.js, control-flow

I have a chain of async functions, which need to be performed in order. Yet, if one of those functions fails or takes too long, it should be retriggered a certain amount of times.

So my questions is:
What is the standard/elegant structure to have such a control flow with async functions? E.g.:

```
funcA()
    .then(resultA => funcB(resultA)
        .then(resultB => funcC(resultB)
            .then(...))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do like this

```
function funcA() {
    return Promise.resolve('a');
}

function funcB(data) {
    return Promise.resolve(data + ' b');
}

function funcC(data) {
    return Promise.resolve(data + ' c');
}

async function controlFlowExample() {
  const resultA = await funcA();
  const resultB = await funcB(resultA);
  const resultC = await funcC(resultB);
  
  console.log(resultC);
}

controlFlowExample();
```

Comment: Ok I see. So the realization for me is to put it all in an async function as well and then handle the control flow.

Answer (score 0):

You can use async-await to chain them neatly together:

```
const res_a = await funcA()
const res_b = await funcB(res_a)
const res_c = await funcC(res_b)
```

This is better than chaining `.then` since here it is easier to debug as you save more values.

Sidenote: if you do it this way, it is best to implement trycatch within your functions.

IMO it looks much neater too.

Comment: It does look cleaner. For my understanding: Does such an 'await' work, if the called async function contains awaits itself?
And can I set timeout for these function calls?

Comment: You can just not await the first expression and that'll be a promise: `const res_a = funcA()` and then do: `const res_b = await funcB(await res_a)`

Comment: you can read more about it here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise